# kdump isnt working on redhat machines

Tags: linux, redhat, coreos, kdump

How to force Linux to crash:

we installed the kexec-tools (kdump) on our redhat machines ( version 7.1 )
in order to capture problems by creating core file under /var/crash folder

we check that kdump is install as

```
 rpm -qa | grep kexec ( verify rpm kdump is installed )
 kexec-tools-2.0.7-19.el7_1.2.x86_64
```

we check the kdump service as

```
# /usr/bin/kdumpctl status 

Kdump is operational
```

we  manually trigger the core dump using the following commands:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

The server should be reboot itself and the crash dump will be generated. Under /var/crash

bot nothing was happend

please advice way kdump not trigger the linux machine to reboot?

redhat doc about the KDUMP:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Kernel_Crash_Dump_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Kernel_Crash_Dump_Guide-en-US.pdf

```
more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)


  dmidecode |  grep -i VM
        Manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
        Product Name: VMware Virtual Platform
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about the server? Is this a dedicated box, virtualized container? If it's virtualized there may be issues using kdump if the kernel is outside the container.

Comment: hi Wilbo - I update my quastion